# Engine misfire, low gas mileage, click when gear change

Tags: engine, dodge, misfire, mileage, charger

I got a tune up, radiator and radiator hose, serpentine belt, starter and wheel bearing fixed.
The misfiring, bad mileage and clicking noise didn’t start until after the tune up. What could be wrong? I have a 2016 dodge charger r/t

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Which engine is in your Charger? Are there any codes present (dash light on)? If so, have you had them checked? What was the reason for getting the tune up?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trusting us with your Charger issues! Let's gather some data so that your question can be answered more fully.

1. Let's start with Paulster2's question about why you requested the tune up before.
2. You mention replacing the radiator hose. Was there an overheating even prior to the repairs being made?
3. Where is this clicking coming from? When is it clicking? ie during acceleration or idle?
4. Who did the repairs and do you know where they got the parts? If not, how much did they charge you for the spark plugs and coils? What all did they replace?
5. Is it misfiring all the time or just under load?

Right now, my theory is that the parts used were sub-par quality, UNLESS the tune up was ordered to stop these same issues. If that's the case, then the clicking may be indicative of issues with your valve train, thus why I asked about where it is coming from. Once you've answered the questions here, we can solve your issue. The easiest way to reply is to edit your original post. We're following it, so we'll see the change, just like you saw this one.

Comment: If you have follow up questions for the OP, make them as comments, not as an answer.